# Generate new string variable by concatenating two integer variables with MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation, concat-ws

I apologize for the silliness of the question but am a complete neophyte with MySQL and am having trouble even reading the documentation for this. I have a table with two columns "homeid" and "indid", which are both integer data fields. I want to concatenate these together in a new variable "uid" with a hyphen. Desired output would look like this:

```
uid   homeid   indid
10-1  10       1
10-2  10       2
11-1  11       1
```

I have tried the following code, which does fine through generating the variable "uid" in which the concatenated variables should sit, but doesn't seem to work (though produces no error) beyond that:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
add column uid varchar(10) FIRST; /*adds column uid to table "table_name" as first column*/

UPDATE table_name
SET uid=CONCAT('-' , homeid, indid);
```

Thanks in advance for your help (and patience).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you need here is [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to use a delimiting separator `-`, or change around the arguments to `CONCAT()`:

```
UPDATE table_name SET uid = CONCAT_WS('-' , homeid, indid);
```

OR change around the arguments to `CONCAT()`

```
UPDATE table_name SET uid = CONCAT(homeid, '-', indid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried with both CONCAT_WS and CONCAT and neither works (again with no error). Is it possible that it is because 'uid' is initially populated with NULL values? If so, is there an easy workaround to that? Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to have to do with the SET portion of this as a SELECT query returns the correct values.

Comment: GAH! I am an ass. I just needed to reload the darn table!

Answer (score -1):

please try following query.

```
UPDATE table_name SET uid=CONCAT('-' , homeid, indid) where homeid > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried this too, but, sadly, didn't work. Seems so simple. Arg.